# Why are expected delivery times given as a range?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

On the "Current job" screen in the Route Advisor, the expected delivery time is always given as a range, e.g. "Fri 21:50 - Sat 2:00".

Why is that? I know the second time is the actual deadline and if you miss it, you fail the job, but what's the purpose of the first time? Is there a bonus (or penalty) for delivering the cargo *early*?

I thought this was simply cosmetic, but I've noticed that high-priority delivery jobs tend to have a narrower time window, which I assume is meant to make the job more challenging, but in what way exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I play lots of ETS.

The delivery range provides information on the earliest time, given optimal conditions, that you would be able to deliver the cargo. The latter time, as you pointed out, was the deadline, where arriving afterwards incurs a penalty.

I have not noticed any particular bonus for delivering earlier - other than not being late. I think the first time is really a guide as to when you can reasonably expect to arrive given perfect conditions.

Comment: I guess I speed a lot, then, because most of the time I'm several hours early :)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't played Euro Truck Simulator 2 yet, but from what I gather, it might be because of realism. Most delivery drivers are given a time range when they may arrive and deliver their cargo.

Comment: So what happens in real life when a driver delivers the cargo early? My experience with truck driving is limited to ETS2 and GTA: San Andreas...

Comment: Depends on the company, but most companies make the driver wait if he's not arrived after or at the given start time, and penalties to the delivery company if he's late.

Answer (score 3):

The earliest time is a rough estimation of your arrival time, keeping in mind resting, boat/train travel time, and road travel time at the allowed speeds (although I've noticed it doesn't calculate it very well for roads on which you can drive 90km/h.)

It does not keep in mind that you can rest on boats/trains and therefore it is quite easy to deliver almost a whole day early. There is also no problem with doing so, but no reward other than being done earlier (in-game time) is given either.

Answer (score -1):

In my relatively low amount of experience more money and experience is awarded for getting closer to the first time in the range.

Comment: Interesting. I certainly haven't noticed this. In fact, I just finished a delivery ~5 hours early and my total payout (sans damage penalty) was exactly as originally advertised. Do you have any specific examples where you've been paid less for arriving too early?

Comment: I've never been payed less for arriving too early, but once you get in that time zone, i've been payed more the closer i am to the earlier one, and pay progressively went down as i got closer to the later one.

Comment: I tried a couple of deliveries where I finished within the expected time range (pretty close to the start of the range), but didn't notice any bonuses. What does it show up as on the mission completion screen?

Comment: I played it quite a long time ago, all i remember is a bonus showing up as green text which appeared to be influenced by getting closer to the earlier time, while inside the time range